# Updating JList model causes StackOverflowError

Tags: java, swing

I don't know why but this code causes a StackOverflowError:

```
public void update() {
    DefaultListModel lm = new DefaultListModel();
    if (elements != null)
    for (String elem : elements) {
        lm.addElement(lm);
    }
    jList1.setModel(lm);
    repaint();
    }
```

I tried debugging this and actually the stackOverflowError happens outside (I suppose in the AWT Event queue....), here is what I see in the console:

First this a number of times:

```
at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.toString(DefaultListModel.java:397)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:422)
    at java.util.Vector.toString(Vector.java:940)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.toString(DefaultListModel.java:397)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826)
```

Then it repeats this (all in the same stack trace):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.SizeRequirements.calculateAlignedPositions(SizeRequirements.java:444)
    at javax.swing.BoxLayout.layoutContainer(BoxLayout.java:415)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2476)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.SizeRequirements.calculateAlignedPositions(SizeRequirements.java:444)
    at javax.swing.BoxLayout.layoutContainer(BoxLayout.java:415)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.ensureCurrentLayout(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1429)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.paint(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:770)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:143)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:567)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5131)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:21)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:60)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:97)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1780)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3375)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.SizeRequirements.calculateAlignedPositions(SizeRequirements.java:444)
    at javax.swing.BoxLayout.layoutContainer(BoxLayout.java:415)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.ensureCurrentLayout(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1429)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.paint(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:770)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:143)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:567)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5131)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1479)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1410)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:21)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:60)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:97)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1780)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3375)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.SizeRequirements.calculateAlignedPositions(SizeRequirements.java:444)
    at javax.swing.BoxLayout.layoutContainer(BoxLayout.java:415)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.ensureCurrentLayout(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1429)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.getTabBounds(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1449)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(WindowsTabbedPaneUI.java:86)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$TabbedPaneLayout.layoutContainer(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:2384)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.ensureCurrentLayout(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1429)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.getTabBounds(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1449)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(WindowsTabbedPaneUI.java:89)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:558)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.access$2000(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:37)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mouseMoved(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:3645)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6312)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3285)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6036)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4251)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.SizeRequirements.calculateAlignedPositions(SizeRequirements.java:444)
    at javax.swing.BoxLayout.layoutContainer(BoxLayout.java:415)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.ensureCurrentLayout(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1429)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.getTabBounds(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1449)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(WindowsTabbedPaneUI.java:86)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$TabbedPaneLayout.layoutContainer(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:2384)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.ensureCurrentLayout(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1429)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.getTabBounds(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1449)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(WindowsTabbedPaneUI.java:89)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:558)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.access$2000(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:37)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mouseMoved(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:3645)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6312)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3285)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6036)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4251)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.SizeRequirements.calculateAlignedPositions(SizeRequirements.java:444)
    at javax.swing.BoxLayout.layoutContainer(BoxLayout.java:415)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.ensureCurrentLayout(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1429)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.getTabBounds(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1449)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(WindowsTabbedPaneUI.java:86)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$TabbedPaneLayout.layoutContainer(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:2384)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.ensureCurrentLayout(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1429)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.getTabBounds(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:1449)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(WindowsTabbedPaneUI.java:89)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.setRolloverTab(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:558)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI.access$2000(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:37)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mouseMoved(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:3645)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6312)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3285)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6036)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4251)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
```

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see a StackOverflowError, just a repetition of the NPE, which comes from the thread constantly trying to `calculateAlignedPositions`.

Comment: SORRY MATES, REALLY STUPID ERROR, DELETE THE QUESTION

Answer (score 3):

You're adding the list as element to itself, which of course results in endless recursion when you try to recursively convert it to a String:

```
lm.addElement(lm);
```

You probably meant this:

```
lm.addElement(elem);
```

The `NullPointerException`s may disappear after you fix this, or they may be completely unrelated.